# Why doesn't the MediaRecorder function cause ANR error?

Tags: android

I start a service to reord screen using MediaRecorder and MediaProjection function in Android 5.1 , I think the code **Method 1** will cause Application Not Responding error because it works in main thread.

1. I test the code **Method 1** to recode screen long time, it doesn't occur  "Application Not Responding error", why? Does it mean that the function MediaRecorder and MediaProjection worked in separated thread?
2. In the code **Method 2**, I create a thread to run  mRecordHelper.StartRecord(mRecordArg,resultCode,mIntent); but I get the error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(),` why?

Thanks for your help.

**Call Code**

```
MPublicPar.RecordArg mRecordArg =new MPublicPar().new RecordArg(mContext);
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,bll.RecordService.class);
intent.putExtra("resultCode",resultCode);
intent.putExtra("dataIntent",data);
intent.putExtra("mRecordArg",mRecordArg);

startService(intent);
```

**Method 1**

```
public class RecordService extends Service { 

    private RecordHelper mRecordHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){  
        mContext=this;

        mRecordHelper=new RecordHelper(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        mRecordHelper.StopRecord();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       final int resultCode=intent.getIntExtra("resultCode",0);
       final Intent mIntent=(Intent)intent.getParcelableExtra("dataIntent");
       final MPublicPar.RecordArg mRecordArg=(MPublicPar.RecordArg)intent.getSerializableExtra("mRecordArg");

        mRecordHelper.StartRecord(mRecordArg,resultCode,mIntent);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

**Method 2**

```
public class RecordService extends Service { 

    private RecordHelper mRecordHelper;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){  
        mContext=this;

        mRecordHelper=new RecordHelper(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        mRecordHelper.StopRecord();
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

       final int resultCode=intent.getIntExtra("resultCode",0);
       final Intent mIntent=(Intent)intent.getParcelableExtra("dataIntent");
       final MPublicPar.RecordArg mRecordArg=(MPublicPar.RecordArg)intent.getSerializableExtra("mRecordArg");    

       new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {    
                mRecordHelper.StartRecord(mRecordArg,resultCode,mIntent);           
            }
        }).start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

**RecordHelper.cs**

```
public class RecordHelper {

    private  MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private  MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private  VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private  MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;

    private Context mContext;
    private Toast mToastText;

    public RecordHelper(Context mContext){
        this.mContext=mContext;
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    public void StartRecord(RecordArg mRecordArg, int resultCode, Intent data){

        initRecorder(mRecordArg);
        prepareRecorder();

        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);

        mVirtualDisplay=createVirtualDisplay(mRecordArg);

        DelayStartRecord(mRecordArg);
    }


    public void StopRecord(){
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();

            mVirtualDisplay.release();
            mMediaRecorder.release();

            mMediaProjection.stop();
            mMediaProjection = null;

        }catch (Exception e){
            Utility.LogError("StopRecord Error " + e.getMessage() + "  " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void DelayStartRecord(RecordArg mRecordArg){
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }


    private void initRecorder(RecordArg mRecordArg) {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mRecordArg.screenWidth, mRecordArg.screenHeight);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mRecordArg.videoFilename);
    }


    private void prepareRecorder() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utility.LogError(e.getMessage());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Utility.LogError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay(RecordArg mRecordArg) {
          return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("ScreenRecord",
                 mRecordArg.screenWidth, mRecordArg.screenHeight, mRecordArg.mScreenDensity,
                 DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                 mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null /*Handler*/);
    }


    //Called when the MediaProjection session is no longer valid.
    private  class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: in method 2 I think you should put it  on ui Thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I get the error java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare(), why?

i guess you know hence your second question. The fact that if you call `mRecordHelper.StartRecord(mRecordArg,resultCode,mIntent);` on the Main thread, does not mean all code functions runs on that thread, all it does is it updates the UI informations on the calling Thread-which is the main thread, and the hard work on a background Thread. if you xplicitly call from a different thread you are instructing it to change a UI object from that thread hence you get that exception- picture a class using async task, or `SurfaceView`, do not get confused sir, you can always go check the source code and see how it works.

*This is not a big deal -(i humbly speak)*

> why? Does it mean that the function MediaRecorder and MediaProjection worked in separated thread?

check the above -i guess yes

Comment: Thanks! Is there a office document to tell me that MediaRecorder and MediaProjection worked in separated thread ?